# newlines in my mailto link are broken on Android phones

Tags: javascript, android, mailto

I have a web application that I'm trying to optimize for mobile and my straightforward mailto function isn't working on the default mail client on my Android phone.  It works in the gmail client, but not in the native one for integrating with Exchange emails. (It also seems to work on iphones fwiw.)  What's happening in the native client is that everything after a carriage return is cut off.  So say I have something like the following:

```
    sendLinkByEmail: function (subject, message, url)
    {
        var parsedMessage = encodeURIComponent("Isn't this cool?\n I am sending you an email!");
        var emailLink = "mailto:?Subject=" + encodeURIComponent(subject) + "&body=" + parsedMessage;
        window.location = emailLink;
        return false;
    }
```

If I choose to open with the Gmail app, I see what I expect:

> Isn't this cool?
>
> I sent you an email!

But if I open it with the Mail app, I just get

> Isn't this cool?

and that's it.

Same thing happens if instead of \n I use %0A or %0D%0A or if I don't use encodeURIComponent (e.g. the message is just literally "Foo%0D%0ABar"--I just get Foo).

I cannot figure out what that stupid mail client is doing!  Anyone have any idea?

Thanks very much!!!

---

Just realized my problem is even greater--the moronic mail client also truncates anything after even an encoded & (%26)  So I can't embed a URL either, which is the whole point of the function.

Is there any alternative to mailto for opening the mail client from a web application?

Comment: I guess I'm tripping over Bug 8023.  Grr.  http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=8023

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, your success with \n in a mailto: link will vary from mail client to mail client. What I've found to work best is using %0d in place of \n, but even then, not all clients will support it.

If formatting is important to you, a mailto: link is not what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the response (however disappointing the fact!) I wouldn't mind if the formatting didn't show up on all clients, but having it cut off the end of the message is unacceptable.  So I have to remove the formatting for all clients even though most can handle line breaks just fine.  Darn.  So if a mailto link is not what I want, what can I do from a *webapp* (not native) to open the email client on the phone?

Comment: Unfortunately, mailto: links are your only option if your objective is to open a native mail client. Otherwise, you could send the content using your own mail implementation, but obviously the user will not have access to their local address book. Sufficed to say, this is a shortcoming of the implementation.